# How do I dynamically populate a page with divs with onClick functions that modify an HTML5 video player?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

As the overly specific title makes clear, I'm trying to use javascript to dynamically add divs to a page (based on how many videos I have to load for the HTML5 media player) and I want each of the divs to have a separate onclick function that changes the source of the media player.

I've gotten the page to dynamically add divs, but the divs do not have onClick functions despite me assigning them during the creation process. After some (read: a lot) of googling, I found that the problem is I can only reference a function, not put specific code in an onClick event (I think?) So, I changed up the code, and now I have this:

```
<video name = "myVideo" style = "width: 500px; height: 300px" id = "player" controls = "controls" autoplay = "autoplay">  
<source name = "VidSource" src = 'video.mp4'>  
<source name = "VidSource" src = 'video2.webm'>  
</video><br><br><br>  


<script type = "text/javascript">  
var sourceName = document.getElementsByName("VidSource");  

for (x = 0; x< sourceName.length; x = x+1)  
{  
    var stringToSend = sourceName[x].src;  
    var substringint = stringToSend.lastIndexOf("/");  
    stringToSend = stringToSend.substring((substringint + 1));  
    createDiv("Div" + x, 250, 40, stringToSend);  

    document.write("<br>");  
}  

function createDiv(id, width, height, toWrite)  
{  
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');   
    newdiv.id = id;  
    newdiv.style.width = width;  
    newdiv.style.height = height;  
    newdiv.style.overflow = "auto";  

    newdiv.style.background = "#FF0000";  
    newdiv.style.border = "2px solid #FFFFFF";  

    var substringint = toWrite.lastIndexOf("/");  
    toWrite = toWrite.substring((substringint + 1));  

    newdiv.innerHTML = " <center> " + toWrite + "</center>";  
    newdiv.onClick = "changeSrc(" + toWrite ");";   
    document.body.appendChild(newdiv);  
}  

function changeSrc(src)  
{  
    document.myVideo.src = src;  
    video.load();  
    video.play();  
}  


</script>
```

So, what that outputs is simply the media player, and no divs at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I'm missing something extremely obvious, but no amount of searching is helping me to find the error I'm making.

Answer (score 0):

The onclick attribute [is spelled](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html) with a lowercase 'c'. That might be your problem.

But the [W3C model](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html) for registering events is to use `addEventListener` instead of assigning to the `onclick` attribute. [This tutorial](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html) shows how. I would use that model for better portability (or better yet, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which takes care of all the portability concerns).

**Edit**: Oh yes, and as you said in the question (but didn't reflect in the code), you need to assign a *function* (whether you use `onclick` or `addEventListener`), not a string containing code. So where you have:

```
newdiv.onClick = "changeSrc(" + toWrite ");";
```

instead, use:

```
newdiv.onclick = function() { changeSrc(toWrite); };
```

or:

```
newdiv.addEventListener("click", function() { changeSrc(toWrite); }, false);
```

or best yet (most portable), using jQuery (requires that you import that library):

```
$(newdiv).click(function() { changeSrc(toWrite); });
```

This is much easier to avoid making a mistake, since you don't need to concatenate strings and form your own JavaScript syntax: note that in the string version you would need to quote `toWrite` and escape any special characters, which isn't needed in the function version.

Comment: I changed it as you said would work, using newdiv.onclick = function() {changeSrc(toWrite);};

Doing so did make the divs appear, however I'm now back to square one. The divs are appearing, but there is no onclick function in them (neither working, nor when you inspect the element with google chrome).

Thanks for the help, and do you have any idea what else might be messed up? I'm going to try it with addEventListener now and see if that fixes anything.

Comment: Hmm ... well assigning directly to the `onclick` attribute works for me in both Firefox 4 and Chromium 10. Both handle the click correctly, and both let me see the function if I type into the console `newdiv.onclick`. So I don't know what could be wrong. Try putting a simple `window.alert("")` in the handler function and see if it comes up.

Comment: If you're going to try the jQuery option use: $(newdiv).live("click",function() { changeSrc(toWrite); }); This ensures that any future "newdiv" elements will also have the action.

Comment: @Ian Devlin Sounds cool, but will it work for a jQuery object built from a DOM element, not a selector? I was assuming `newdiv` was a DOM element (non-jQuery) and `$(newdiv)` therefore wraps it up in jQuery. How will `live` know about any future "newdiv" elements when they weren't found using a selector? In fact I think this specific usage is ruled out under "caveats" on the documentation page.